# How to change grafana units of measurement on Y-axis?

Tags: monitoring, memory, graph, graphite, collectd

I am gathering data from servers by collectd and store it in the graphite.
I want to use grafana dashboards. I am trying to create visualisation for memory plugin. In graphite I am seeing data in Mb, but in grafana graph I see strange "Mib" or "Bil" on the Y-axis. 
How can I change grafana units of measurement?

Answer (score 5):

Custom unit formats are not supported at this moment.

Workaround: choose "none" for Unit Format (to disable units on legend and tooltip), and put whatever you want to the Label field, or to the Graph title.

Some comments: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/999